# Javascript - convert string to boolean?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to make the `options.isdedicated` as boolean `true` or `false` instead of `string`?

```
<?php $isdedicated = file_get_contents("/home/www/html/config.ini"); //echoed true?>
<script>
  var options = [];
  options.isdedicated = "<?php echo $isdedicated;?>";
  if(options.isdedicated) {
  }
  else {
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JSON format, but you should not quote it:

```
options.isdedicated = <?= json_encode($isdedicated == 'true') ?>;
```

Comment: $isdedicated will be a string, since it is the file-contents, so the json-encoded value will be still a string ;)

Answer (score 1):

Does the config.ini strictly contains `true` or `false`? Then skip the qoutes:

```
<script>
    options.isdedicated = <?php echo $isdedicated ?>;
    ...
```

So your HTML becomes

```
<script>
    options.isdedicated = true;
    ....
```

If you can't be sure the file stricly contains either `true` or `false` (e.g. can be user input), just make sure you can only print `true` or `false` in JavaScript (so no JavaScript can be [injected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

```
options.isdedicated = <?php echo $isdedicated === 'true' ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this would work

```
options.isdedicated = "<?php echo $isdedicated;?>" === 'true';
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this work?

```
options.isdedicated = "<?php echo $isdedicated;?>" == 'true' ? true : false;
```

Comment: NO , its still not boolean type inside double quotes.

Comment: options.isdedicated = "<?php echo $isdedicated;?>" == 'true' ? true : false;